# laravel ajax redirect after login

Tags: ajax, session, redirect, laravel

I have a global like button that allows only authenticated users to like a post. This is done via ajax so when a user is not authenticated gets redirected to /login.

Problem is that I don't have the after login redirect location. The laravel built-in Redirect::intended is not working because the filter is applied via ajax. So when user gets authenticated how can I redirect him back to where he pressed the like button. ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably are using Json response data. return status code 401. with the following structure

```
{
    success: false,
    message: "You need to log in to like a post"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by saving the location to the session. I do this in the controller's constructor. I just thought maybe there would be a more elegant way.